# Microsoft Edge session (open tabs) lost following Windows update

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge, tabbed-browsing

Using Windows 10 I have installed a recent large update (probably Fall Update, v1511) which have created the C:\Windows.old directory and reinstalled parts of the core OS.

Anyway, my "Microsoft Edge" browsing session was lost and all recent tabs are no longer available. The official documentation says nothing about this, but I wonder if there is a way to recover them.

Specifically, I have found I still have many files under `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Recovery\Active` which some forum questions suggested that *deleting* all the files there may *clear the browsing session* (the inverse of what I want), so I wonder if they can be used to *recover* it.

Comment: Windows 10 does not have Service Packs.  I assume you mean you installed the (Fall Update, Version 1511) update?  If you delete the files in that directory then any chance of recovery will be lost.  You recover a lost  session in Edge the same way you do so in Internet Explorer, you take the recovery session and put it in the folder for the current session.  I don't have my Windows 10 system handy to tell you what that is specifically but I have done that many times for IE personally.

Comment: That sounds like a promising directions, but I cound not find the path of the current session.

Comment: Its in a folder within `../MicrosoftEdge\User\Default/` there might not be nothing in the folder.  If you could give a directory listing I post an answer, otherwise, I will post one tonight.  I have experience with this [precise problem](http://superuser.com/questions/740813/ie11-startup-tabs-restore-last-session-not-working), just with IE, so I have done what I describe hundreds of times.

Comment: Don't you see them in your browsing history?

Comment: @Vinayak - Its a complicated history.  Even if those sites are, the session, shouldn't have been lost but it can be recovered given certain criteria ( i.e. the recovery session is indeed the session that the author wants to restore ).