# Why doesn't my private session in Edge always clear when I close all my InPrivate windows?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, private-browsing

Sometimes, I've noticed in Microsoft Edge that even after I close all my InPrivate windows, my cookies and data saved in that session don't clear properly. They remain separate from my main, non-private session, but don't clear. The session is supposed to clear whenever all InPrivate windows are closed.

After some investigation, I noticed that after closing all Edge windows, both regular and InPrivate, there are still one or more latent Microsoft Edge processes running. Terminating those processes causes the session data to be cleared; my next InPrivate window is a whole new session. However, if I don't do so, my session still remains not cleared even though all Edge windows are closed. I also discovered that this also works by terminating all Edge processes even with a regular window still open; this has the added advantage that regular tabs also reopen and my private session is cleared.

Why are there still latent Edge processes running even after I close all InPrivate windows, that prevent the session data from being cleared? Is this a bug, since the documentation clearly states that closing all InPrivate windows will clear my private session data? If it's a bug, is there a way I can terminate all such processes automatically after closing all InPrivate windows?

**Update:** I discovered that I can work around this issue by terminating any "Background Tab Pool" processes in Task Manager in case closing all InPrivate windows didn't clear my session.

Comment: “If it's a bug, is there a way I can terminate all such processes automatically after closing all InPrivate windows?” - Yes; It’s a big.  Write a batch script to close the process.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm also interested in knowing why this bug happens.

Comment: [Bug exists with IE11](https://superuser.com/questions/740813/ie11-startup-tabs-restore-last-session-not-working) while I accepted an answer and the behavior seemed to have stopped I have noticed it every once in awhile.  It’s possible an application I used caused, me to have multiple IE stored sessions, but Edge is based on IE.  I noticed the behavior in earlier builds of Edge.